# EmptyStackException

Tags: java, stack

This EmptyStackException continues to pop up.  Obliviously there is nothing in my stack, but the first element that the User inputs.  However, I am not sure where the code is flawed. (many spots) but I just need to fix this error.

```
import java.util.*;

public class stacks2 {

public static void main (String []args){
System.out.printf("Enter a math equation in reverse polish notation:\n");

//Create stack of Strings
Stack<String> rpnStack = new Stack<String>();
//Create Scanner 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//String in = input.next();

while(input != null) {
    String in = input.next();
        // Tokenize string based on spaces.
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in, " ", true);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
             rpnStack.push(st.nextToken());
         }
    //Send stack to Calculation Method
    calculate(rpnStack);
     }
}

public static void calculate(Stack<String> stack) {
    // Base case: stack is empty => Error, or finished
    if (!stack.isEmpty())
      // throw new StackUnderflowException("Empty Stack");

    // Base case: stack has 1 element, which is the answer => finished
    if (stack.size() == 1)
        System.out.printf("Finished, Answer: %s\n",stack.peek());

    // Recursive case: stack more elements on it.
    if (stack.size() > 1){
        String temp1 = stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        String temp2 = stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        String temp3 = stack.peek();
        stack.pop();


            if (temp3.equals("+")){
            float resultant = Float.parseFloat(temp1) + Float.parseFloat(temp2);
            stack.push(String.valueOf(resultant));
            //System.out.println(resultant);
            calculate(stack);
            }

            if (temp3.equals("-")){
            float resultant = Float.parseFloat(temp1) - Float.parseFloat(temp2);
            stack.push(String.valueOf(resultant)); 
            //System.out.println(resultant);
            calculate(stack);
            }

            else if (temp3.equals("*")){
            float resultant = Float.parseFloat(temp1) * Float.parseFloat(temp2);
            stack.push(String.valueOf(resultant)); 
            //System.out.println(resultant);
            calculate(stack);
            }

            else if (temp3.equals("/")){
            float resultant = Float.parseFloat(temp1) / Float.parseFloat(temp2);
            stack.push(String.valueOf(resultant)); 
            //System.out.println(resultant);
            calculate(stack);
            }

            else{
            System.out.printf("Something severely has gone wrong.");
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

the input and error:

```
:~ Home$ java stacks2
Enter a math equation in reverse polish notation:
4 5 * 6 -
Finished, Answer: 4
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:85)
at stacks2.calculate(stacks2.java:41)
at stacks2.main(stacks2.java:22)
```

clearly this is only taking the first element which makes me think my while loop at 17 is the cause. Any insight?

Answer (score 5):

`String in = input.next();` reads you one word, then you are trying to tokenise that word. Perhaps you meant `String in = input.nextLine();`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

---

Also, you have these two lines in your code.

```
if (!stack.isEmpty())
  // throw new StackUnderflowException("Empty Stack");
```

This is plain wrong. Without its curly braces, the `if` affects the next statement. It is not the comment - it is the following if.

This:

```
if (!stack.isEmpty())
// throw new StackUnderflowException("Empty Stack");

// Base case: stack has 1 element, which is the answer => finished
if (stack.size() == 1)
    System.out.printf("Finished, Answer: %s\n",stack.peek());
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if (!stack.isEmpty())
    if (stack.size() == 1)
        System.out.printf("Finished, Answer: %s\n",stack.peek());
```

and this:

```
if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.size() == 1){
    System.out.printf("Finished, Answer: %s\n",stack.peek());
}
```

Moral: always use curly brackets with an `if` AND don't comment out assertions. Even if you do comment out assertions, comment them completely, and not one half of them, epecially when the other half is an un-bracketed if.

---

Third, your logic is flawed. You do this:

push all symbols to the stack, then pop the top three and consider them an operator and two numbers. This will work with **some** inputs **if** you use a queue instead.

```
4 5 * 6 -
```

By your logic, this will pop `* 6 -` and crash. If you use a queue, it will work **in this case**

```
4 5 * 6 - 
20 6 -
14
```

But not is this case:

```
(1+1)*(1+1)
express as RPN
1 1 + 1 1 + *
2 1 1 + *
```

Next, you pop 2 1 1 and crash.

***Instead, what you should do:***

```
Read the input. For each symbol:
  if it is a number,
    push it on the stack.
  else,
    pop two numbers from the stack,
    perform the operation and
     push the result.
```

Comment: Thanks. I will take note of that.

Answer (score 0):

A stack is LIFO, or "Last in, First out".  So when you have an input sequence of `4 5 * 6 -` and do this:

```
rpnStack.push(st.nextToken());
```

The first thing you pop will be "-", the second thing will be "6", and the third thing will be "*".  Is this what you expect?

Also, instead of:

```
String temp1 = stack.peek();
stack.pop();
```

You can do:

```
String temp1 = stack.pop();
```

Comment: That was not what I was expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging, sys, time
import jenkins from jenkinsapi.jenkins 
import Jenkins from jenkinsapi.build 
import Build from collections import OrderedDict

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```