# EmptyStackException - Java Depth First Search algorithm on 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm, exception, stack, depth-first-search

I have looked at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063282/emptystackexception) I tried most of the code samples from there but when i use it in my code it just skips the algorithm.

I have this DFS algorithm that uses stack, I am getting a `EmptyStackException`, I have debugged the algorithm and after first recursive search the stack is empty, the first search works but then the size of stack is set to 0, What am I missing here? [github](https://github.com/WojciechTeodorowicz/Islands-and-Bridge)

How can I make sure that the stack is not empty after the first search?

The line that I get the exception on is  `while(true){AddBridges state = gameTree.peek(); ...`

I am using a 2d Array to generate the nodes at random from 0 to 4 `0 = null 1-4 = island` The array generates Random Integers every time the user starts the game, could that cause the Algorithm to brake,

After a weekend of debugging I found that the algorithm sometimes brakes after 4-6 searches, and sometimes breaks after the first search.

```
public int[][] debug_board_state_easy = new int[4][4];

//This Generates random 2d array
private void InitializeEasy() {
   Random rand = new Random();

   setCurrentState(new State(WIDTH_EASY));
   for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state_easy.length; row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state_easy[row].length; column++) {
          debug_board_state_easy[row][column] = Integer.valueOf(rand.nextInt(5));
      }
  }

  for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state_easy.length; row++) {
     for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state_easy[row].length; column++) {
        System.out.print(debug_board_state_easy[row][column] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println(debug_board_state_easy);
  }
//I am applying the search algorithm here...
  this.search();

  for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH_EASY; ++row) {
     for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH_EASY; ++column) {
         getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column] = new BoardElement();
         getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges = Integer.valueOf(debug_board_state_easy[row][column]);
              getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].row = row;
              getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].col = column;

         if (getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges > 0) {
            getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].is_island = true;
         }
      }
   }
}

void search() {
   Map<Point, List<Direction>> remainingOptions = new HashMap<>();
   Stack<Land> gameTree = new Stack<>();
   gameTree.push(new AddBridges(debug_board_state_easy));

   while(true) {
      AddBridges state = gameTree.peek();
      int[] p = state.lowestTodo();
      if (p == null)
         System.out.println("solution found");
      // move to next game state
         int row = p[0];
         int column = p[1];
         System.out.println("expanding game state for node at (" + row + ", " + column + ")");

         List<Direction> ds = null;
         if(remainingOptions.containsKey(new Point(row,column)))
            ds = remainingOptions.get(new Point(row,column));
         else{
            ds = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
               int[] tmp = state.nextIsland(row, column, dir);
               if(tmp == null)
                  continue;
               if(state.canBuildBridge(row,column,tmp[0], tmp[1]))
                  ds.add(dir);
            }
            remainingOptions.put(new Point(row,column), ds);
         }
      // if the node can no longer be expanded, and backtracking is not possible we quit
         if(ds.isEmpty() && gameTree.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("no valid configuration found");
            return;
         }
      // if the node can no longer be expanded, we need to backtrack
         if(ds.isEmpty()){
            gameTree.pop();
            remainingOptions.remove(new Point(row,column));
            System.out.println("going back to previous decision");
            continue;
         }

         Direction dir = ds.remove(0);
         System.out.println("connecting " + dir.name());
         remainingOptions.put(new Point(row,column), ds);

         AddBridgesnextState = new AddBridges(state);
         int[] tmp = state.nextIsland(row,column,dir);
         nextState.connect(row,column, tmp[0], tmp[1]);
         gameTree.push(nextState);
      }
   }
}
```

Add bridges class

```
public class AddBridges {

    private int[][] BRIDGES_TO_BUILD;

    private boolean[][] IS_ISLAND;
    private Direction[][] BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT;

    public Land(int[][] bridgesToDo){
        BRIDGES_TO_BUILD = copy(bridgesToDo);

        int numberRows = bridgesToDo.length;
        int numberColumns = bridgesToDo[0].length;
        BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT = new Direction[numberRows][numberColumns];
        IS_ISLAND = new boolean[numberRows][numberColumns];
        for(int i=0;i<numberRows;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberColumns; j++) {
                BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j] = null;
                IS_ISLAND[i][j] = bridgesToDo[i][j] > 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public AddBridges (AddBridges other){
        BRIDGES_TO_BUILD = copy(other.BRIDGES_TO_BUILD);
        int numberRows = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
        int numberColumns =  BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;
        BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT = new Direction[numberRows][numberColumns];
        IS_ISLAND = new boolean[numberRows][numberColumns];
        for(int i=0;i<numberRows;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberColumns; j++) {
                BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j] = other.BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j];
                IS_ISLAND[i][j] = other.IS_ISLAND[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] next(int r, int c, Direction dir){
        int numberRows = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
        int numberColumns = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;

        // out of bounds
        if(r < 0 || r >=numberRows || c < 0 || c >= numberColumns)
            return null;


        // motion vectors
        int[][] motionVector = {{-1, 0},{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}};
        int i = Arrays.asList(Direction.values()).indexOf(dir);

        // calculate next
        int[] out = new int[]{r + motionVector[i][0], c + motionVector[i][1]};

        r = out[0];
        c = out[1];

        // out of bounds
        if(r < 0 || r >=numberRows || c < 0 || c >= numberColumns)
            return null;

        // return
        return out;
    }

    public int[] nextIsland(int row, int column, Direction dir){
        int[] tmp = next(row,column,dir);
        if(tmp == null)
            return null;
        while(!IS_ISLAND[tmp[0]][tmp[1]]){
            tmp = next(tmp[0], tmp[1], dir);
            if(tmp == null)
                return null;
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public boolean canBuildBridge(int row0, int column0, int row1, int column1){
        if(row0 == row1 && column0 > column1){
            return canBuildBridge(row0, column1, row1, column0);
        }
        if(column0 == column1 && row0 > row1){
            return canBuildBridge(row1, column0, row0, column1);
        }
        if(row0 == row1){
            int[] tmp = nextIsland(row0, column0, Direction.EAST);
            if(tmp == null)
                return false;
            if(tmp[0] != row1 || tmp[1] != column1)
                return false;
            if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[row0][column0] == 0)
                return false;
            if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[row1][column1] == 0)
                return false;
            for (int i = column0; i <= column1 ; i++) {
                if(IS_ISLAND[row0][i])
                    continue;
                if(BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[row0][i] == Direction.NORTH)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        if(column0 == column1){
            int[] tmp = nextIsland(row0, column0, Direction.SOUTH);
            if(tmp == null)
                return false;
            if(tmp[0] != row1 || tmp[1] != column1)
                return false;
            if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[row0][column0] == 0 || BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[row1][column1] == 0)
                return false;
            for (int i = row0; i <= row1 ; i++) {
                if(IS_ISLAND[i][column0])
                    continue;
                if(BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][column0] == Direction.EAST)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        // default
        return true;
    }

    public int[] lowestTodo(){
        int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
        int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;

        int[] out = {0, 0};
        for (int i=0;i<R;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[i][j] == 0)
                    continue;
                if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]] == 0)
                    out = new int[]{i, j};
                if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[i][j] < BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]])
                    out = new int[]{i, j};
            }
        }
        if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]] == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    private int[][] copy(int[][] other){
        int[][] out = new int[other.length][other.length == 0 ? 0 : other[0].length];
        for(int r=0;r<other.length;r++)
            out[r] = Arrays.copyOf(other[r], other[r].length);
        return out;
    }

    public void connect(int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1){
        if(r0 == r1 && c0 > c1){
            connect(r0, c1, r1, c0);
            return;
        }
        if(c0 == c1 && r0 > r1){
            connect(r1, c0, r0, c1);
            return;
        }
        if(!canBuildBridge(r0, c0, r1, c1))
            return;

        BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0]--;
        BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1]--;

        if(r0 == r1){
            for (int i = c0; i <= c1 ; i++) {
                if(IS_ISLAND[r0][i])
                    continue;
                BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[r0][i] = Direction.EAST;
            }
        }
        if(c0 == c1){
            for (int i = r0; i <= r1 ; i++) {
                if(IS_ISLAND[i][c0])
                    continue;
                BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][c0] = Direction.NORTH;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do a better job of attempting to debug yourself. You didn't even give it 10 minutes from your last question (which you have now deleted) before posting this one... Find out why `int[] tmp = state.nextIsland(row,column,dir);
            nextState.connect(row,column, tmp[0], tmp[1]);` is returning nothing

Comment: @IsThisJavascript  have spent a lot of time debugging the algorithm, i feel like im going in circles here, The algorithm works for the first search then tries to back tracking and the stack `size = 0`, `if(ds.isEmpty()){
                gameTree.pop();
                remainingOptions.remove(new Point(row,column));
                System.out.println("going back to previous decision");
                continue;
            }
` This is the loop for backtracking.

Comment: For quick and efficient help, please post [mcve]. I can't debug the (too) long code without running it.

Comment: It's difficult to follow what your search is trying to find, but whatever it is, are you certain that it will always be present?  Because the meaning of a correct DFS backtracking past the initial state is that the search failed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The search is trying to find If there is a value > 0 in the array, if there is mark that point check if can be connected NORTH SOUTH EAST or WEST, if it can it pushes the state to the stack this works "sometimes", if not it will go back to previous state and try a different point.

Comment: It is suspicious that when you find a solution (`if (p == null)`) you do not exit the search loop.

Comment: That's the other thing i have found out that `p is never = null` but the states in the stack change. I am very confused, It's my first time trying to implement an DFS algorithm

Comment: The standard way to implement a DFS iteratively via a stack starts with creating a stack initially containing only the starting node.  Then, on each iteration, you pop the top element from the stack, and test whether it's the one you're looking for.  If so, you exit the loop.  If not, then you push *all* the successor nodes you want to traverse from the current node.  If on any iteration there is no node to pop, then the search has exhausted all nodes without finding one satisfying your criteria; this is not ordinarily a hard error.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Actually, the standard way to implement a DFS is to use recursion with a visited flag, a stack is mainly used for BFS. Since the OP is talking about DFS, I can understand the confusion.

Comment: That's quite beside the point @rdlopes.  The OP is trying specifically to implement an (explicitly) stack-based DFS.  I described the standard way for writing *that kind* of DFS implementation.  Also, BFS uses a queue, not a stack.  That can in fact be considered the only essential difference between the two.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you're right, I'm out of the point and your remark is completely relevant, sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One part of your question stood out to me as the root of the problem: "What am I missing here"? Unit tests, unless I just didn't see them in your project.

Questions like "the array generates Random Integers every time the user starts the game, could that cause the Algorithm to brake?", are the reason unit tests exist, along with the following:

1. In the course of writing tests on sections of code that don't end up
   being the problem, you'll prove definitively that they aren't the
   problem.
2. If the code you're working with can't be tested as-is, or
   is "too complex" to test, re-writing it will make you a better
   designer and will often lead to "I can't believe I didn't see that"
   moments.
3. When you refactor this program (reduce complexity, rename variables to make them easier to understand, etc), you'll be notified immediately if something breaks
   and you won't have to spend another weekend trying to figure it out.

As an example, instead of randomizing the board within the method that searches it, randomize it elsewhere and then drop it into that method as an argument (or into the class' constructor). That way, you can initialize your own test board(s) with your own supplied values and see if some boards work better than others and why. Split up larger methods into smaller methods, each with their own parameters and tests. Aim to make a program out of smaller confirmed-working pieces, instead of making a huge thing and then wondering if the problem is the small part you think it is or something else.

You'll save so much time and frustration in the long run, and you'll end up leagues ahead of those who code for hours and then debug for hours.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in the code, but the first thing I notice might help:

```
// if the node can no longer be expanded, we need to backtrack
            if(ds.isEmpty()){
                gameTree.pop();
                remainingOptions.remove(new Point(row,column));
                System.out.println("going back to previous decision");
                continue;
            }
```

you pop from the stack, and continue onto the next while(true) iteration, at that point, there may be nothing on the stack since you have not added anything else.

Comment: How can sure not to pop the stack while its value is 1?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Rosa -

The EmptyStackException should occur when removing or looking up empty Stack-

======Iteration/State in code   ======

```
 **if(ds.isEmpty()){**  //HashMap isEmpty = true and gameTree.size() = 1
            gameTree.pop();    // After removing element gameTree.size() = 0 (no elements in stack to peek or pop)
            remainingOptions.remove(new Point(row,column));
            System.out.println("going back to previous decision");
            continue;  //Skip all the instruction below this, continue to next iteration
        }
```

========Next iteration========

```
  while(true){
            AddBridges state = gameTree.peek(); // gameTree.size() = 0 and a peek
```

operation shall fail and program will return EmptyStackException.

Required isEmpty check -

```
if(gameTree.isEmpty()){ 
            System.out.println("no valid configuration found");
            return;
        }
        AddBridges state = gameTree.peek();
```

As, no actions have been performed by function but while loop. In case other instcutions to be processed , a "break" is required.

Comment: I am stuck in a infinite loop, Its getting the same values and tries to build bridges all over again